# Activate a certain data tab from another page in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

Suppose, in my webpage, I have a sidebar menu containing three tabs like: notice, news and events. If I click on any of the tab, corresponding items become visible at a specific place in the page which were kept hidden using display:none property. Coding format is as follows:

```
<div class="sidenav">
            <div class="panel-header-silver">
                <h2>Upcoming</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="sidenav-item sidenav-active" data-tab="notices" >
                General Notices
            </div>

            <div class="sidenav-item " data-tab="News" >
                News
            </div>
            <div class="sidenav-item" data-tab="Events">
                Events
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now, I want to link to any tab from another page. That means, if I click a link it will activate the news tab (say). Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Pass the tab name as a get parameter like this `pageurl.php?tab=News` In that page based on parameter add the `active class`  `(sidenav-active)` to particular tab.

Comment: "In that page based on parameter add the active class to particular tab"- can you please explain this? @JYoThI

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code. You need to pass the "data-tab" value of the Element you want to make Active, on button click.

```js
// Page 1.html Script

function activeButton(value) {
  window.location.href = '2.html#active=' + value;
}

// Page 2.html Script
$(document).ready(function() {
  var activeTab = getUrlParameter('active');
  console.log(activeTab);
  $(".sidenav").find(`[data-tab='${activeTab}']`).addClass("active");

});

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var results = new RegExp('[\?&#]' + sParam + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
  if (results == null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="panel-header-silver">
    <h2>Upcoming</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-item sidenav-active" data-tab="notices">
    General Notices
  </div>

  <div class="sidenav-item " data-tab="News">
    News
  </div>
  <div class="sidenav-item" data-tab="Events">
    Events
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:activeButton('News')">  Active </a>
</div>
```

Edit : I have modified the above function to get parameter name in URL using "#" too.

Comment: Much simpler getting url params using URL API and URL.searchParams()

Comment: can you please explain? @charlietfl

Comment: is there any way to use link (say: https://www.example.com#News) to activate the News tab? @Charu Maheshwari

Comment: @user10184297 Updated the answer as per your requirement. Please check.